# Get a single column of matrix from a text file in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL language and wish to know how can I do the following process. Assume I have a program that creates a text file per single run and should be run for 10000 times. Every single run creates and text file called "OUT.out". All I am interested is a single number in a specific column from that OUT.out file in a single run.

Ideal case for a single run should be as following:

- Start the main Run, (should be repeated for 10000 times, assumed)

  - Run Case 1
  - Finish the Case 1

    - Open the text file, OUT.out.

      - Find the maximum absolute value in the 4th column of the text file.
      - Save the max value in a separate text file in row 1.
    - delete the OUT.out file
  - Run Case 2
  - Finish the Case 2 of the main loop

    - Open the text file, OUT.out.

      - Find the maximum absolute value in the 4th column of the text file.
      - Save the max value in a separate text file in row 2.
    - delete the OUT.out file
  - Run Case 3
  - Finish the Case 3 of the main loop

    - Open the text file, OUT.out.

      - Find the maximum absolute value in the 4th column of the text file.
      - Save the max value in a separate text file in row 3.
    - delete the OUT.out file
  - Run Case 4
    .
    .
    .

I presume code should be shorted that my note. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Independent of the answer for how to read the text file, with that many files you're going to have some _fun_ problems. Like not fun at all run-out-of-file-handles or break-the-filesystem-for-too-many-files-in-a-directory sort of fun. You really ought to look into storing your results in a database like SQLite. (This is friendly advice from someone who's been there and received the battle scars…)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what the separator is, you might do:

```
# Read in the data and list-ify it; REAL data is often messier though
set f [open OUT.out]
set table [lmap row [split [read $f] "\n"] {split $row}]
close $f

# Kill that unwanted file
file delete OUT.out

# Tcl indexes start at 0
set col4abs [lmap row $table {
    expr { abs([lindex $row 3]) }
}]

# Get the maximum of a list of values
set maxAbs [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}$col4abs]

# You don't say what file to accumulate maximums in
set f [open accumulate.out "a"];  # IMPORTANT: a == append mode
puts $f $maxAbs
close $f
```

and then repeat that after each run. I'm sure you can figure out how to do that bit.

But if you're doing this a lot, you probably should look into storing the results in a database instead; they're *much* better suited for this sort of thing than a pile of ordinary files. (I can thoroughly recommend SQLite; we moved our bulk result data management into it and greatly improved our ability to manage things, and that's keeping lots of quite big binary blobs as well as various chunks of analysable metadata.)